# Why don't I have a menu for "object" in Particle Properties?

Tags: particles, interface

I am trying to do a bit of dynamic painting with a particle system to make some rainy puddles, but I can't choose the object for my particles, because there is no object menu?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your particle system is already attached to an object, its name will be in the top corner of the settings, where I've outlined.  Yours is 'Plane.001'

But if you are looking for the object to render as the particles, you need to click the '>' next to the word "Render".  When you do a panel will open that looks like this:

[image: Particle Settings with Render open]

If the word *Object* doesn't appear in the box next to the words "Render as", click on the box and select object.

Once you've done that, the *Object* panel appears and you can select the render objects in it.